# Thin line on the right side on mobile browser view in React application in Chrome

Tags: css, reactjs, layout

The issue is that this white vertical line (empty space) appears on the right side of the screen when entering mobile mode in Chrome only. The css is minimal in my case, there is styled #root item. I tried to add `overflow-x: hidden;` to tags body and html, as many of you recommend, but it does not help. I wander what could be the reason, why this space appears.. Did anyone faced this issue before? The code is basic:

```
body, html, #root {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Thank you!

```
[Unwanted space between #root and body]:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIs0u.jpg